# Bash reference to "parent" Git branch when creating branch off of another branch

Tags: bash, git, github, command-line

Let's say I have a branch called `parent-branch` and I create a branch right off of that branch by doing

```
git checkout -b child-branch parent-branch
```

That's all fine and well of course, but what I am looking (*hoping*) to do, is to be able to somehow reference `parent-branch` from within a bash script. So for example, something like `git_current_branch` and `git_main_branch` will print the current local branch I am in, and print the `master` branch, respectively.

Is there a way where I can do something like `git_parent_branch` (*or something along those lines*) to have access to the `parent-branch` in bash and the command line. Whether that be a bash script function, or whatever other potential possibilities might work.

Is there something involving GitHub and / or any associated APIs perhaps where this is possible. I'm not overly familiar with connecting to GitHub other than just using their web interface, so anything in that respect would most likely be of big help (*ideally pertaining to my issue here*)!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Git at a fundamental level, branches simply don't *have* parents.  Well, I say *simply*, but it's not that simple, because we haven't *defined* branch, and users of Git use the word very loosely and often mean different—and contradictory, sometimes—things when they say it.  So let's define *branch name* first, which at least has a simple, definite meaning:

- A *branch name* is a name whose full spelling starts with `refs/heads/`, which—in order to exist—contains the hash ID of some existing, valid commit.

The last bit here—which is kind of redundant: an existing commit is valid, and a valid commit (whatever that means) must exist—is a concession to the fact that we can have branch names that *don't* exist (yet, or any more): `xyzzy`, for instance, is fine as a branch name, but until you *create* it, it's just a sort of potential branch name, floating in limbo as it were.

Because a branch name *must* contain a commit ID to exist, a new, empty repository—which has no commits—has no branch names either.  And yet you're *on* the initial branch.  It's in limbo, as yet nonexistent.  When you make your first commit in this empty repository, *then* the branch name actually *exists*.  If you like, you can re-create this special case in a *non-empty* repository using `git checkout --orphan` or `git switch --orphan`.  (These are subtly different in how they manipulate Git's index, but both put you in this funky state of being on a branch that does not yet exist.)

This kind of special case aside, because a branch name has to contain some commit hash ID, we normally *create* a branch by picking some existing hash ID, just as in your example:

> ```
> git checkout -b child-branch parent-branch
> ```

But what Git does with this is to resolve the *name* `parent-branch` to a *commit hash ID* first, then create a new branch—in this case, named `child-branch`—containing that hash ID.  The two branch *names* have no parent/child relationship; we could run `git checkout -b daddy kid` or `git checkout -b xyzzy plugh` and there's no parent/child relationships here either, despite the misleading name in the `daddy kid` version and the neutral names in the `xyzzy plugh` case.

Now we come to your own question, though:

> Is there a way where I can do something like git_parent_branch (or something along those lines) to have access to the parent-branch in bash and the command line.

Git contains, as a useful tool—parts of Git make use of this in various ways—a *fully general string-based configuration system*, where we run `git config` to set some arbitrary string to some arbitrary value.  By convention, these strings have a hierarchical structure: `user.name` and `user.email` live within the `user` space; `push.default` is composed of `push` + `default`; and so on.  Git even stores them using an [INI-file-style syntax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INI_file).

What this means is that although *Git itself* has no parent/child relationship, you can *make up your own*.  There are a few obvious drawbacks to doing so:

- Git won't maintain it for you.
- You need to choose names that Git won't clobber, even in some future release (Git version 3.14 perhaps).
- Nobody else will understand what the heck you're doing.

So, if you choose to do this, you're on your own—but let's note that Git *does* store some per-branch information in the `branch.name` namespace:

- `branch.xyzzy.remote` is the *remote* setting for the branch named `xyzzy`;
- `branch.xyzzy.rebase` is the `git pull` setting controlling whether the second command to use is `git merge` or `git rebase`, and depending on which second command *is* to be used, what flags, if any, to pass to that second command, when you're on branch `xyzzy` and you run `git pull`;
- `branch.xyzzy.description` is the descriptive text that `git format-patch` will include in a cover letter, when run for branch `xyzzy`;

and so on.  So if you were to add a `branch.name.parent` string value, you could store your string here.  You then merely need to hope that the Git developers don't steal that name—`parent`—from you in the future.

Since this stuff *is* totally free-form, you'd just run `git symbolic-ref` or similar to *find* the current branch name, then `git config --get branch.$branch.parent` to get its parent setting, if it has one.  If it does not have one, this must be a normal everyday parentless Git branch, rather than one of your own specially decorated branches that *does* have a nominal parent.  To *set* the parent for some branch, you'd run `git config branch.$branch.parent $parent`, where `$parent` is the setting you want.  (It's your decision as to whether `$parent` is required to be a *branch* name, in which case strings like `xyzzy` and `main` and `plugh` are fine, or whether it could be a *remote-tracking name* as well, in which case, you'd better use fully-qualified strings like `refs/heads/xyzzy`, `refs/heads/main`, and so forth.  That will allow you to use `refs/remotes/origin/main`—a remote-tracking name—as a "parent".)

> Is there something involving GitHub and / or any associated APIs perhaps where this is possible.

Definitely not, and this points up another weakness in the idea of using `branch.$name.parent`: there is no way to *record* this data on GitHub.  It's a purely local setting.  Then again, *branch names* are purely local: there's noting that requires that you call *your* development branch `dev` or `develop`, even if the development branch name in some GitHub repository you've cloned is called `dev` or `develop`.

Before I finish this off, let me add another several definitions of *branch*.  We'll needs a few more definitions as well:

- A *branch tip* is the commit to which a *branch name* points.  That is, given some branch name like `main` that indicates some particular commit hash ID such as `a123456...`, the *tip commit* of branch `main` is `a123456...`.  Checking out a branch *by* its name—with `git checkout` or `git switch`—and then *adding* a commit *automatically stores the new commit's hash ID in the branch name*, so that the tip commit *automatically advances*.  The new commit's parent will be the old branch tip.
- A *branch* (in one of its many meanings) is *a set of commits that includes the tip commit of a branch* (with *branch* here meaning *name that contains a commit hash ID*).  Where this set of commits *begins* is in the mind of the user, but if left unspecified, Git generally includes *every commit reachable from the tip commit*.
- To define *reachable*, see [Think Like (a) Git](http://think-like-a-git.net/).
- A *remote-tracking name* is a name that exists in your Git repository but was created due to a branch name that your Git saw in some *other* Git repository.  These names live in the `refs/remotes/` namespace, which is further qualified by the *remote*, such as `origin`.  For instance, `refs/remotes/origin/main` would be a remote-tracking name in your repository, in which your Git remembers the hash ID stored in `origin`'s branch name `main`, the last time your Git got an update from their Git.
- For some users, a *remote branch* is a branch (in the meaning of *series of commits terminating at a tip commit*) where the tip commit is given by a remote-tracking name.  For other users—or the same user speaking at some other time—a *remote branch* is a branch that exists in some remote repository, such as `origin`.  These two are easily conflated since your own `origin/main` *tracks* the other Git's `main`, hence the term *remote-tracking name*.  (Git calls this a *remote-tracking branch name*, but the adjective *remote-tracking* in front of the noun *name* seems sufficient here.)

As you can see, the word *branch* is so loosely defined as to be nearly valueless.  We can often reconstruct the correct definition—the one a speaker or writer had in mind—based on context, but for clarity, it's often better to use some other term.

Comment: Wow, holy moly! That was an amazing plethora of information, and extremely helpful. Thanks so much for taking the time to explain all that so thoroughly. Very, very much appreciated!!

Comment: Some of this was me writing down (for the first time) a few background thoughts I have on improving(?) `git rebase` to handle multi-branch rebasing, for which we desperately need some kind of "related branches" configuration. But what that relation is and how to encode it aren't entirely clear.